# How to get get png from CustomPainter in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

I think the question makes it clear however it I want a png from the pattern drawn on the screen using canvas ,How do I do that,Here is my code..I have tried everything Currently due to time constraints I am using RepaintBoundary to take the screen shot of the complete stack however I need a better functionality..Any pointers?...I have tried looking but could'nt find any solutions as of yet.I am working on a signature pads of sorts which takes the users signature and posts it online as a png, I am able to get the user to draw on the screen and take a screenshot of the whole stack but cant obtain a Png from just the drawn pattern

```
class SignaturePainter extends CustomPainter {
  Paint _paint;
  SignaturePainter(this.points, this._paint);
  final List<Offset> points;
  List<Offset> offsetPoints = List();
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
      if (points[i] != null && points[i + 1] != null)
        canvas.drawLine(points[i], points[i + 1], _paint);
      if (points[i] != null && points[i + 1] == null) {
        offsetPoints.clear();
        offsetPoints.add(points[i]);
        offsetPoints.add(Offset(points[i].dx + 0.1, points[i].dy + 0.1));
        canvas.drawPoints(ui.PointMode.points, offsetPoints, _paint);
      }
    }
  }

  bool shouldRepaint(SignaturePainter other) => other.points != points;
}

class Signature extends StatefulWidget {
  SignatureState createState() => new SignatureState();
}

class SignatureState extends State<Signature> implements ClearScreen {
  List<Offset> _points = <Offset>[];
  Paint backgroundPaint, foregroundPaint;
  GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();
  @override
  void initState() {
    backgroundPaint = new Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 5.0;
    foregroundPaint = new Paint()
      ..color = Colors.amber
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 5.0;

    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: appGradient,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: RepaintBoundary(
          key: globalKey,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                  RenderBox referenceBox = context.findRenderObject();
                  Offset localPosition =
                      referenceBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
                  setState(() {
                    _points = new List.from(_points)..add(localPosition);
                  });
                },
                onPanEnd: (DragEndDetails details) => _points.add(null),
                onPanStart: (details) {
                  setState(() {
                    RenderBox referenceBox = context.findRenderObject();
                    Offset localPosition =
                        referenceBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
                    _points = List.from(_points)..add(localPosition);
                  });
                },
              ),
              CustomPaint(
                painter: SignaturePainter(_points, backgroundPaint),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0.0,
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Button("Proceed", Alignment.bottomLeft, this, 0),
                          Button("Redo", Alignment.bottomRight, this, 1),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void clearScreen() {
    setState(() {
      _points.clear();
    });
  }

  @override
  void performProceedTapAction() async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
        globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
    ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    var extern = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String path = extern.path;
    int random = Random(10000).nextInt(1000000);
    File file = new File("$path/image-$random.png");
    await file.writeAsBytes(pngBytes).then((onValue) {
      print(onValue);
    });
  }
}

abstract class ClearScreen {
  void clearScreen();
  void performProceedTapAction();
}

class Button extends StatelessWidget {
  final String buttonText;
  final Alignment alignment;
  final ClearScreen mListener;
  final flag;
  const Button(this.buttonText, this.alignment, this.mListener, this.flag);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: alignment,
      child: Container(
        height: 60,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
        child: Card(
          elevation: 10,
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 149, 208, 158),
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              if (flag == 1) {
                mListener.clearScreen();
              } else if (flag == 0) {
                mListener.performProceedTapAction();
              }
            },
            child: Center(
                child: Text(
              buttonText,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                  fontSize: 20),
            )),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: check `PictureRecorder` class

Comment: Picture recorder can be used with a canvas which I declare on my own here as you can see the instance of canvas that is used to draw is provided by paint method ... I am sorry but this is totally confusing ..I have tried that too

Comment: create a `Canvas` and pass it to `SignaturePainter.paint` method

Comment: wouldnt that require the change of the whole drawing logic ,I have seen this mentioned before too but could not replicate the same successfully ... could you edit the above code to show me how ?

Comment: no - you dont have to change anything - just create a brand new `Canvas` and pass it to your `SignaturePainter.paint()` method

Comment: Ok ! could you please point out where in the above flow should I pass the canvas because I cant figure this out .The performProceedTaskAction method is called when the whole operation is to be completed... could you be more specific because this is the first time I am experimenting with canvas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207739/discussion-between-faizan-mir-and-pskink).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @pskink for his guidance here is how the bug was solved ,I am posting the code in full for someone else's use

```dart
class SignaturePainter extends CustomPainter {
  Paint _paint;
  SignaturePainter(this.points, this._paint);
  final List<Offset> points;
  List<Offset> offsetPoints = List();

  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
      if (points[i] != null && points[i + 1] != null)
        canvas.drawLine(points[i], points[i + 1], _paint);
      if (points[i] != null && points[i + 1] == null) {
        offsetPoints.clear();
        offsetPoints.add(points[i]);
        offsetPoints.add(Offset(points[i].dx + 0.1, points[i].dy + 0.1));
        canvas.drawPoints(ui.PointMode.points, offsetPoints, _paint);
      }
    }
  }

  bool shouldRepaint(SignaturePainter other) => other.points != points;
}

class Signature extends StatefulWidget {
  SignatureState createState() => new SignatureState();
}

class SignatureState extends State<Signature> implements ClearScreen {
  List<Offset> _points = <Offset>[];
  Paint backgroundPaint, foregroundPaint;
  GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();
  SignaturePainter signaturePainter;

  @override
  void initState() {
    backgroundPaint = new Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 5.0;

    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    signaturePainter = SignaturePainter(_points, backgroundPaint);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: appGradient,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                RenderBox referenceBox = context.findRenderObject();
                Offset localPosition =
                    referenceBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
                setState(() {
                  _points = new List.from(_points)..add(localPosition);
                });
              },
              onPanEnd: (DragEndDetails details) => _points.add(null),
              onPanStart: (details) {
                setState(() {
                  RenderBox referenceBox = context.findRenderObject();
                  Offset localPosition =
                      referenceBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
                  _points = List.from(_points)..add(localPosition);
                });
              },
            ),
            CustomPaint(
              painter: signaturePainter,
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0.0,
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Button("Proceed", Alignment.bottomLeft, this, 0),
                        Button("Redo", Alignment.bottomRight, this, 1),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void clearScreen() {
    setState(() {
      _points.clear();
    });
  }

  @override
  void performProceedTapAction() async {
    ui.PictureRecorder recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(recorder);
    try {
      signaturePainter.paint(canvas, Size.infinite);
      print(canvas.hashCode);
      ui.Picture p = recorder.endRecording();
      ui.Image image = await p.toImage(
          MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.toInt(),
          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.toInt());
      ByteData byteData =
          await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
      print(byteData.buffer.asUint8List());
      var external = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
      String path = external.path;
      File file =
          new File("$path/image-${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.png");
      await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List()).then((onValue) {
        print(onValue);
      });
    } catch (exception) {
      print(canvas.hashCode);
      print("Exception Thrown $exception");

      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "Something went wrong,try resubmitting",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          timeInSecForIos: 1,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade500,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 16.0);
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
}

abstract class ClearScreen {
  void clearScreen();
  void performProceedTapAction();
}

class Button extends StatelessWidget {
  final String buttonText;
  final Alignment alignment;
  final ClearScreen mListener;
  final flag;
  const Button(this.buttonText, this.alignment, this.mListener, this.flag);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: alignment,
      child: Container(
        height: 60,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
        child: Card(
          elevation: 10,
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 149, 208, 158),
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              if (flag == 1) {
                mListener.clearScreen();
              } else if (flag == 0) {
                mListener.performProceedTapAction();
              }
            },
            child: Center(
                child: Text(
              buttonText,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                  fontSize: 20),
            )),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```